# How to get the html string exactly like IE renders it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mshtml

I am having some problem to get the exactly same HTML string as rendered by IE10. There're some slight difference between the one rendered by IE 10, and the one I retrieved with WebClient.DownloadString(url). (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824081/difference-between-ie-10-rendered-html-and-its-output-html))

How to get the **exactly** same HTML string? Do I need to simulate the Browser behavior?

Comment: Browsers will automatically adjust some aspects of the source to make an object model that they can render.  The only entirely reliable way would be some form of simulation/automation and then retrieval of the DOM from memory.

Comment: That essentially means I have to launch IE to browse the URL, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is duplicated with this one: [How to get the page source from an IE window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842277/how-to-get-the-page-source-from-an-ie-window)

And I have solved it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the user-agent header for IE10 to your request:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)");
```

Depending on your scenario (mobile, x64, etc.), the header might have different values. See [IE10 User Agent String Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/12/ie10-user-agent-string-update.aspx) for other examples.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but not working. Actually, I add all the headers that IE 10 sent, still no luck.