# How to get the page source from an IE window?

Tags: internet-explorer, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, mshtml

I need to parse the page source as rendered by IE.

I can use the following simple code to open an IE to a URL.

(The BrowserWinodw type is from the Visual Studio Coded UI test framework.)

```
BrowserWindow bw = BrowserWindow.Launch(url);
```

How to get the page source from the IE window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do it. Use the IHtmlDocument2 interface. With reference to this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292485

I will share my code snippet shortly.